# Golang Clean shutdown on Signal Interrupt

Tags: go, concurrency, signals, goroutine

I am trying to find an efficient way to shutdown all my go routines, once i get my OS interrupt signals. Here i am polling events (say from some queue) and processing it in a goroutine. But when i receive OS interrupt, i want to make sure the jobs that are on fly are completed before they are terminated. I also need some additional thing to do only after all the goroutines are completed. The below code seems to work fine for me, but is there any better/efficient way to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time" // or "runtime"
)

func something(wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("something is happening here...")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("job done...")
}

func main() {

    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    mutex := sync.Mutex{}
    stop := make(chan int, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    count := 0
    go func() {
        <-c
        currentTime := time.Now()
        fmt.Println("Interrupt signal got at: ", currentTime.String())
        // do not let the code shutdown without running everything we needed to do
        mutex.Lock()
        stop <- 1
        fmt.Println("Done .. try shutting down")
        wg.Wait()

        // do cleanup
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)

        fmt.Println("All cleanup completed .. shut down")
        currentTime = time.Now()
        fmt.Println("Kill at : ", currentTime.String())
        mutex.Unlock()
    }()

    // This for loop is for reading messages from queue like sqs, and it has to be infinite loop because there might be scenarios where there are no events for period of time.
    for {            
        // read off of queue
        select {
        case stop <- 1:
            fmt.Println("Not stopped yet")
            wg.Add(1)
            go something(&wg)
            <- stop
            count ++
        default:
            // try getting the lock before exiting (so that other cleanups are done)
            mutex.Lock()
            fmt.Println("Done! All jobs completed: Jobs count",count)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Processing job -", count)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find these useful

https://guzalexander.com/2017/05/31/gracefully-exit-server-in-go.html

https://medium.com/@matryer/make-ctrl-c-cancel-the-context-context-bd006a8ad6ff

Comment: Awesome article. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your solution is unnecessarily complicated. It might be correct, but this is much simpler:

```
func goroutine(wg *sync.WaitGroup,stop chan struct{}) {
  defer wg.Done()
   for {
     select {
       case <-stop:
          return
       default:
     }
    // do stuff
  }
}

func main() {
 stop:=make(chan struct{})

 // Setup signal handlers
 go func() {
        <-c
        // This will send the stop signal to all goroutines
        close(stop)
 }()
 // Start goroutines
 ...
 // wait for them to finish
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense and using "close" is way cleaner. But i have that infinite loop ("for" loop at the end) as my bottle neck, and i can't wg.wait() after that (becomes unreachable code). Lets say I have some distributed queueing system (sqs/3rd party event system, which returns irregular number of events everytime you query and the queue is always busy) where we get like 10 msg at one long polling, and 5 at the next loop. I don't want the 5 messages to wait till the first 10 messages are completed.

Comment: The solution is still valid if you create multiple goroutines to deal with the messages. You should not need that for-loop.

Comment: Yep works, Just put that entire thing in goroutine and it works. Thanks